# DynamoDB updateItem not working

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-php-sdk

I have the following DynamoDB update query using php SDK.

```
$up = $this->dynamoDb->updateItem(array(
            'TableName' => $this->dynamoTable,
            'Key' => array(
                'id' => array('S' => $id),
                'time' => array('N' => $time)
            ),
            //"ReturnValues" => 'UPDATED_NEW',
            "UpdateExpression" => "SET #moderated = :val",
            "ExpressionAttributeNames" => array(
                "#moderated" => "changes_applied",
            ),
            "ExpressionAttributeValues" => array(
                ':val' => array('N' => 1)
            )
        ));
        debug($up);
```

But it is not working. When I print the returned result, I am getting the same record before update.

Can anybody help me on figuring out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have commented the return value. If ReturnValues is not specified, then nothing is returned.

```
//"ReturnValues" => 'UPDATED_NEW',
```

**Use:-**

```
"ReturnValues" => 'ALL_NEW',
```

> ALL_NEW - Returns all of the attributes of the item, as they appear
>   after the UpdateItem operation.

Comment: Still getting the same result. Data not updated. Any idea what will be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To whoemever finds this relevant now. The OP forgot to place the number in quotations:

```
$up = $this->dynamoDb->updateItem(array(
        'TableName' => $this->dynamoTable,
        'Key' => array(
            'id' => array('S' => $id),
            'time' => array('N' => $time)
        ),
        //"ReturnValues" => 'UPDATED_NEW',
        "UpdateExpression" => "SET #moderated = :val",
        "ExpressionAttributeNames" => array(
            "#moderated" => "changes_applied",
        ),
        "ExpressionAttributeValues" => array(
            ':val' => array('N' => '1') // CHANGE HERE
        )
    ));
    debug($up);
```